# How to do pattern searching in fire base real time DB

Tags: firebase

Fire base searching i have done lots of R&D but couldnt

```
 I have lots of entries in DB,
    I want pattern searching like this ,
    expected input:output
        1)`j`:`jignesh`,`jack`,`jigx`
        2)`ji`:`jignesh`,`jigx`
    I want this this of searching from fire base real time DB 
    something like `SQL like Query`
```